# Add property foreach object with php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have two arrays object:

```
$seo_items      = collect($resource->items)->values();
$api_items      = collect($api_items)->values();
```

And, I want to iterate these elements and add the property **size**, which belongs to the `$api_items` array to the `$seo_items` array.

```
foreach($seo_items as &$seo_item)
{
     foreach($api_items as $item) 
     {

        if($item->article_id == $seo_item->article->article_erp_id) 
        {
             $seo_item->article->size == $item->size;
             $items_result[] = $seo_item;
        }

     }
}
```

The problem is that I can not assign this value, because `php` report this error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$size
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please show result set of $seo_items and api_items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is result of typing. 
You have used == ( comparison operator), which is comparing with property which doesn't exist,instead of assigning the value.

```
 $seo_item->article->size == $item->size;
```

changing it to

```
 $seo_item->article->size = $item->size;
```

Should resolve your problem.